# Memory allocation fails when using Valgrind

Tags: embedded, valgrind

I am trying to debug an embedded application with Valgrind.
Unfortunately, this application behaves differently than when I run it without Valgrind. At one point a driver allocates a data block of about 4 MB. This allocation fails even though there is still about 90 MB of memory available. Could it be that Valgrind fragments the memory so much that no contiguous block of that size is available anymore?
Does anyone have an idea how to remedy this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an embedded system at all. Other than that, why would Valgrind fragment memory? It's the heap allocation algorithm in your C lib doing that. It's impossible to tell why it fails without more details about the system and C lib used.

Comment: "This doesn't sound like an embedded system at all.
"Can you explain this further?

Comment: Embedded systems don't use heap allocation and they typically don't have some 100Mb of RAM either.

Comment: Of course, you can also allocate memory dynamically in an embedded system.
It is a PowerPC P2020 with a total of 500 MB RAM running a Linux.

Comment: That's a PC then.

Comment: I do not want to discuss the definition of an embedded system here ;-)

Comment: Valgrind default tool `memcheck` itself consumes memory. Can you run application with the tool `none`: `valgrind --tool=none ...`?

Comment: With --tool=none it seems that the application isn't started at all.

Comment: How can you tell that the application does not start with `none`?

Comment: The process does not exist and the log messages that the application normally writes do not appear in sylog.